# Show list of tasks to asssociate when commiting to a git repository from Visual Studio 2008-2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008

We are swapping from TFVC to GIT and using TFS2013, IDE enviroments VS2010 VS2008 - we cannot convert projects to higher version. Now my task is to find out if there is way, where you can commit on a **Task** with having overview what **Tasks** that are assigned to me. And can one choose from Task in some kind of GUI where to commit in VS2008/2010.

Normally you would mark your commit by # + number of task. Our managment ask if there is way same in VS2013 - you can just choose from list on what task you want to commit on.

Comment: A bit of an aside, but you do know that VS2010 projects/solutions can be opened in VS2012/VS2013 without affecting the ability to open in VS2010?

Comment: Good point, Apply even for VS2008?

Comment: I'm afraid the "feature" of backwardly compatible solutions was new for VS2012

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Visual Studio 2013, there is an option on the "Changes" panel that allows you to associate work items from a work item query as well:

[image: Changes Panel]

You can open a Query and then drag/drop the work item on the "Changes" tab to associate them. It will result in an automatic additional message in the commit message.

With regards to older versions of Visual Studio, the 2012 version has limited Git support out of the box, this has largely been improved in 2013 and even more in 2015 (coming soon).

Depending on the project types you're using in your 2010 and 2012 solutions, you may be able to use [Solution Round-tripping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx). Not all project types in 2010 and 2013 *can* be opened in Visual Studio 2013. Visual Studio 2008 projects cannot be changed to support roundtripping. When you open these in a newer version of Visual Studio, they will be upgraded with no way back.

There is an [open source Git provider for 2010 available](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c), with [an older version for Visual Studio 2008](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/releases/view/46589), these don't integrate with Work Item management, but at least allows you to commit directly from the solution explorer. **What you can do, is to stage your commit from Visual Studio 2008-2012, then do the final commit from Team Explorer 2013.**

The last way is through WebAccess, which allows you to associate a commit to a work item post-commit/post-push. This "link to existing item" option is only available from the web portal in TFS 2013.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for info, from your answer i estimate that there is no way to achieve what we exactly need.  Most of ours project are in VS2008 with vdproj installations packages - this so called Solution Round-tripping wouldn't be for any kinda of good use.

Comment: Correct. But you would be able to use the open source provider to prepare the commit and then commit and push from Team Explorer 2013 installed along side.

Comment: aware of it. I try to propose it to others and see what they say, thanks man